# Django {{ user }} does not return user object in templates without generic views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

If some template requests from generic views I can get `{{ user }}` and it will be an object of authenticated user (e.g. me).

But if I work without generic views, with usual views `{{ user }}` does not return my object.

Why???

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't included it in your template render context.

You need to use something like:

```
def my_view(request, …):
    …
    return render_to_response("my_template.html", {
        …,
        "user": request.user,
    })
```

Comment: No problem. If you want, could make `user` available automatically using a context processor (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/).

Comment: I've read that docs, but haven't seen how to make 'user' available automatically in templates. Do you know any short way? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @VitaliPonomar you might have figured out this already but I m still asking did you `'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth'` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS `

Comment: {{ user }} is still not available after you add the context processor if you use `render_to_response`. be sure to see Catavaran's answer to solve this

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `render_to_response()` then you need to add third parameter with RequestContext instance:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          {'my_data', my_data},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

More details at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response